# Ajax Sorting and Filtering Is Not Working in MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-5.1

On each index view page which contain list, I'm using ASP.NET MVC AJAX to sort and filter the list. The list is in the partial view. Everything looks so fine until I have a view with a parameter (reference key/FK)

I don't add any routes, just using the default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

so the url is `http://localhost:49458/TimeKeeper/New?billingID=7`. If the url in that format, the AJAX sort and filter are not working. I tried to add a new route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "TimeKeeperNew",
    url: "TimeKeeper/New/{billingID}",
    defaults: new { controller = "TimeKeeper", action = "New", billingID = "" }
);
```

so the url become: `http://localhost:49458/TimeKeeper/New/7`.
Now, the ajax sort and filter are working.

Is there anyone can explain me, what's the problem? Did I use the correct way (by adding a new route) or is there any other way?

Comment: Litterally `"billingID" != "id"`.

Comment: @ErikPhilips I see, usually `{id}` is the primary key right? but `billingID` is the foreign key of Timekeeper table. I need to display data by the `billingID`. Could you explain more deeply? Any other way or is that the correct way?

Comment: Why not just pass the parameter as `id` - you can still filter the data - `db.TimeKeepers.Where(x => x.BillingID == ID)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Thanks, it also works with `{id}`. So `{id}` is not only for PK, but FK or any other field right? What about if there are 2 parameters, let's say `billingID` and `clientGroupID`? I don't quite understand routing in depth, could you help me to explain this in the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't even understand why you are saying primary key as MVC has no concept of this.

With only (assuming for the duration of this answer until the break):

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Default",
  url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Home", 
                  action = "Index", 
                  id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Any route that does not define `id` will be appended to the url with the value.

```
Url.Action("New", "TimeKeeper", new { billingID = 7 })
```

Always will produce

```
http://localhost:49458/TimeKeeper/New?billingID=7
```

Because `"billingID" != "id"`

So your options are another `MapRoute` which I would not recommend, or use `Id`:

```
Url.Action("New", "TimeKeeper", new { id = 7 })
```

which always produces:

```
http://localhost:49458/TimeKeeper/New/7
```

Optionally:

```
public class TimerKeeperController
{
  public ActionResult New(string id)
  {
    int billingId;
    if (!string.TryParse(id, out billingId)
    {
      return RedirectToAction("BadBillingId")
    }
    ....
  }
}
```

**BREAK**

> What about if there are 2 parameters, let's say billingID and clientGroupID? I don't quite understand routing in depth, could you help me to explain this in the answer?

Now you need another MapRoute:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Default2",
  url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{id2}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Home", 
                  action = "Index", 
                  id = UrlParameter.Optional,
                  {id2} = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

And it **is required to be before or after the previous MapRoute** because anything that would work for this route will work for the previous route, thus this route will never be called. I can't exactly remember which way it goes at the moment, but if you test it, you'll figure it out quickly.

Then you can have:

```
 http://localhost:49458/TimeKeeper/Copy/7/8
```

with:

```
  public ActionResult Copy(string id, string id2)
  {
    ....
  }
```

**notes**

Yes you don't have to use a string and parse the values, you could use constraints on the MapRoute or just use Int and throw errors if someone manually types `http://localhost:49458/TimeKeeper/New/Bacon`.

Comment: I think {id} is the primary key, but it isn't. Thank you for the explanation.